# Extracting words surrounding anchor text

Tags: java, html

I need help in using java code to extract some words that are surrounding the anchor text of html content.In particular seven words before and after (both sides of) the anchor text(HTMl block-level elements and punctuation marks included).

Comment: You should provide sample input text and what you want extracted.

Comment: for ex: href=http://.... "anchor text" sometext. from this i want to extract the text preceeding "anchor text" and the ones following "anchor text".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/java.html) for this.

Comment: Ya thanks..but i couldnt construct the regex for my purpose..Plz help me with a regex to perform my task

Answer (score 0):

You want to create new URL() from href and get only host part? Get a look at this class.

To find anchors and get href attribute I recommend Jericho library. I'm using it always when I need to parse a sample of HTML / XML and need no XML validation. It's fast and easy to use, and has a lot of examples on project's page.